# Setting From: in Email via PHP mail function

Tags: php, email

I am using the mail function

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'From: <>' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";  
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

I want to pass the email-value for "From:" as a variable. Can this be done? And how can I pass other values like mobile number on to the mail?

Comment: This is pretty much answered in the examples in the documentation.  It's just a string and strings can be composed by concatenating mixtures of string literals and variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the email address($fromAddress) as a header

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <'.$fromAddress.'>' . "\r\n".
             'Reply-To:'.$fromAddress. "\r\n" .
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got this. Its perfectly working. Can you please tell me how to send some more stuffs in mail like contact number. How can i add this in the mail function?

Comment: you can pass it in the body ($message)

Answer (score 2):

From [example2 in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)..

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```